# Use hadoop HDFS from c++, undefined reference to `hdfsConnect'

Tags: c++, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Does any one succeed to use hdfs from c++, using hadoop 2.6.0?

I have trying to compile this peace of code:

```
#include "hdfs.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
    const char* writePath = "/tmp/testfile.txt";
    hdfsFile writeFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, writePath, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0, 0, 0);
    if(!writeFile) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing!\n", writePath);
          exit(-1);
    }
    char* buffer = "Hello, World!";
    tSize num_written_bytes = hdfsWrite(fs, writeFile, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    if (hdfsFlush(fs, writeFile)) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Failed to 'flush' %s\n", writePath);
          exit(-1);
    }
    hdfsCloseFile(fs, writeFile);
}
```

Here is listing of my folders:

```
$ ls ${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}
bin  etc  include  lib  libexec  LICENSE.txt  logs  NOTICE.txt  README.txt  sbin  share

$ ls ${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/include
hdfs.h  Pipes.hh  SerialUtils.hh  StringUtils.hh  TemplateFactory.hh

$ ls ${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/lib/native
libhadoop.a  libhadooppipes.a  libhadoop.so  libhadoop.so.1.0.0  libhadooputils.a  libhdfs.a  libhdfs.so  libhdfs.so.0.0.0
```

I'm trying to compile using this command, and get errors:

```
g++ -I${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/include -L${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}/lib/native -lhdfs -lhadooputils -o hdfs_test hdfs_test.cpp
/tmp/ccyYER8m.o: In function `main':
hdfs_test.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `hdfsConnect'
hdfs_test.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `hdfsOpenFile'
hdfs_test.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `hdfsWrite'
hdfs_test.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `hdfsFlush'
hdfs_test.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `hdfsCloseFile'
```

I understand that I should link some hadoop libraries, but I can't find any documentation. Also I do not have a lot experience in c++.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/james/Desktop/hadoop2.7.2
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin**

add linker settings:
-lhadooppipes
-lhadooputils

add linker search directories:
/lib/native

**BTW:
If you work in a 64-bit system, you need to compile hadoop for 64-bit.**